# Scrapy: No module named 'parsel'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, scrapy, qubes-os

I have searched a lot, but I have not found a solution for this. After installing scrapy, when I try to run it, I am given this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in 
>      from scrapy.cmdline import execute
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/**init**.py", line >34, in 
>      from scrapy.spiders import Spider
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist->    from scrapy.http import >Request
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/http/**init**.py", >line 11, in 
>      from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist->packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 12, in 
>      from parsel.selector import create_root_node
>   ImportError: No module named 'parsel'

I cant find any module named parsel, can anybody give me a clue where I should look?

I am running Qubes OS 3.2. Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it

```
pip install parsel
```

From [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#things-that-are-good-to-know), it is a required package

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already have installed parsel using pip, as outlined in the documentation.